# React: Child State isn't updating after Parent state gets Updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am beginner in Reactjs. I was building an form application using the same. There I was asked to set value of input field from the server, which can be updated by user i.e. an controlled input component.

I fetched the value in parent state then I passed the value to the child state and from there I set value of input field. Now the problem arises when I update the value in parent state then the value isn't getting updated in the child state.

See the code below -

App.jsx

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Child } from "./child";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/2")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setDetails(data));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("data of details", details?.data);
  }, [details]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Testing</h1>
      <Child details={details} setDetails={setDetails} val={details?.data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child.jsx

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export const Child = ({ details, setDetails, val }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    save: true,
    ...val
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue({ ...value, email: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleSave = () => {
    setDetails({
      ...details,
      data: { ...details.data, email: value.email }
    });
    console.log("Data",value);
  };


  const handleDelete = () => {
    setDetails({ ...details, data: { ...details.data, email: "" } });
    console.log("Data",value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="cont">
      <input type="text" value={value.email} onChange={handleChange} />
      {value.save && <button onClick={handleSave}>save</button>}
      <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Codesandbox Link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/testing-m3mc6?file=/src/child.jsx:0-801

**N.B. I have googled for solution I saw one stackoverflow question also but that wasn't helpful for me as I am using functional way of react.**

Any other method of accomplishing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in child component:

```
useEffect(()=>{
 setValue({
    value,
    ...val
  });
}, [val])
```

Comment: Apparently useEffect is working fine. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Can I ask why updating parent state isn't affecting child state? I mean changing state should update it's subscribers right?

Comment: The prop you are passing is taken into consideration only in the first render. Any subsequent prop value changes must be watched using the `useEffect` hook.